# Two different layouts in aurelia app

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I'd like to use two separate layouts for my aurelia app. Difference between them is that one doesn't have a sidebar. Currently I'm using one layout file defined as below:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

If an active route needs this sidebar to appear I'm just putting it into its view.
What I'd like to achieve is to add another layout that would have this sidebar by default:

```
<template>
    <require from="../common/elements/sidemenu/sidemenu"></require>

    <div class="container">
        <sidemenu></sidemenu>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

So the question is - how to do this? Is it even possible with an aurelia app to have multiple layouts (or master pages, however you call those)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use `aurelia.setRoot()`

You can manually set up your application by specifying a script with `configure` instructions in your `index.html`. Typically, this is set to `main`.

**index.html**

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
```

In this script you can specify a root view model using `aurelia.setRoot('root')`. If no argument is provided, the convention is to use `'app'`.

**main.js**

```
aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
```

However, you can inject the `aurelia` object anywhere in your application, and call the `setRoot` function at any time to load a different root view model.

**home.js**

```
@inject(aurelia)
export class HomeViewModel {
    constructor(aurelia) {
        this.aurelia = aurelia;
    }
    doStuff() {
        this.aurelia.setRoot('withSidebar');
    }
}
```

One common use case for this is having a login page, and I've created a complete template for this use case that you can review, clone, or fork here: http://davismj.me/portfolio/sentry/

Comment: Actually, I have one more question. I'd like to `setRoot` when viewmodel loads. If I do it in the constructor or `activate` method, I get `There was no router-view found in the view for...`. Doing it in `attached` or `created` method starts endless recursion. How to go around this? :)

Comment: That behavior makes sense to me. You shouldn't set root while loading is taking place. You should do it before or afterwards.

Comment: It indeed makes sense. However the question is - which place is the best place to do it? I figured I can subscribe to `router:navigation:success` event, but maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: I recommend checking in the main.js file where you want to set root before you set the root. Once you know where to go, set the root. Same to be true on navigation, if someone navigates /to/some/route, before you trigger navigation, check where you want them to go.